# AWS EC2 with public IP respond to IP but not to URL

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance with apache running.
The instance has a public IP.
If I call the page with the IP es: curl http://xx.xx.xx.xxx I get the right page, index.html.
If I call with url: curl http://my.example.com I get

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand
```

my.example.com point to the right IP if I ping it.

I really don't understand what can be wrong.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you shared the IP and domain name, but some people perceive a risk there - there's little risk really. Please also edit your question to include the relevant part of your web server configuration and the relevant part of the web server access / error logs

Comment: Checkl the Apache configuration.

Comment: I didn't include more details about Apache config because I thought they were not relevant, since I thought about a network problem. When I looked logs and configuration, I understood. So, thx for your useful comments and yes, it was useful to post the question here in that way, notwithstanding the down vote

Answer (score 0):

HttpProtocolOptions was set by default to strict and I had an underscore in my vhost.